# Cannot import name 'dump csp header' from 'werkzeug.http'

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I am using Flask to deploy a machine learning model. I am getting an error message saying that I cannot import name `dump_csp_header` from `werkzeug.http`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\aparna\miniconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\aparna\miniconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Aparna\miniconda3\Scripts\flask.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\users\aparna\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from werkzeug.exceptions import abort
  File "c:\users\aparna\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\__init__.py", line 151, in <module>
    __import__('werkzeug.exceptions')
  File "c:\users\aparna\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\exceptions.py", line 71, in <module>
    from werkzeug.wrappers import Response
  File "c:\users\aparna\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .common_descriptors import CommonRequestDescriptorsMixin
  File "c:\users\aparna\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers\common_descriptors.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ..http import dump_csp_header
ImportError: cannot import name 'dump_csp_header' from 'werkzeug.http' (c:\users\aparna\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\http.py)
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the Werkzeug==0.16.1 on my requirements.txt file. This solved my problem.